# How to find and delete 15 days older files with Cron Jobs?

Tags: bash, shell, bin

I want to delete the files, which are older than 15 days. Files directory is

```
/home/app_admin/files
```

There is 100+ folder in the '**files**' directory, I only want to delete the files, which are older than 15 days **without deleting the folders**.

In the 'files' directory, there are many folders like below ↓↓↓

```
16 Jwellary Image Clipping
300 photos to be retouched
Ashraf Amin
Background removal
Background removal and retouching
Brad C
Change wording in a Photoshop file
Color Correct 123 Product Photos
cut out some high res photos
```

I want to delete the files from this folders.

Can anyone please help me to figure out this.

Comment: What have you tried? similar tasks have been solved several times on this site…

Comment: Have you looked at [tmpwatch](http://linux.die.net/man/8/tmpwatch)? Some wheels don't need reinventing.

Answer (score 1):

Check first what would be deleted:

```
find path/to/basedir -mtime +15 -type f
```

If the output looks good, then add `-delete`:

```
find path/to/basedir -mtime +15 -type f -delete
```